# Можно ли в express.js использовать несколько шаблонизаторов?

Tags: node.js, express

Есть проект, состоящий из двух виртуальных частей - админская managment console и публичная. В одной я хочу использовать EJS, а в другой Jade. Это к примеру, для того, чтобы для публичной части можно было выбрать любой понравившийся клиенту (заказчику) шаблонизатор, а админка пусть уже будет на EJS.

Можно ли это реализовать? Хотя бы теоретический костыль какой-то существует?

Comment: А, собственно, в чем проблема-то? Хотя бы теоретические препятствия существуют?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Во-первых, обычно если настраивать шаблонизатор для некоторого расширения файла - то разным шаблонизаторам можно попросту указать разные расширения.

Во-вторых, админку можно выделить в отдельное подприложение:

```
var admin = express()
// ...

var main = express()
main.use('/admin', admin)
```

После такого выделения админку можно настраивать вообще независимо от основного приложения.

Comment: Очень полезный совет, спасибо! Можете дать пример файла `app.js` с такой настройкой? В обычном случае в `module.exports` попадает переменная `app`, не могу понять, как быть в случае когда еще одна такая переменная появится со своими настройками... например в этом файле будет две переменные со своими параметрами `admin = express();` и `main = express();`, что попадет в `module.exports`? не пойму как это реализовать.

Comment: @sanu0074, `app` - это просто имя переменной. В одном месте вы ее экспортируете, в другом - импортируете. Нет никакой необходимости называть ее именно `app`, ей можно дать любое другое имя.

Comment: @sanu0074 в моем примере, основное приложение - это `main`. Можете экспортировать и использовать далее его. Или можете заменить `main` на `app`. Или, если есть желание всех запутать, можете написать вообще так: `module.exports.app = main`.

Comment: Суть в том что мы ее импортируем в пусковом файле и передаем ее в `http.createServer()`, а если у нас их будет две, то как тогда быть? я это имел виду...

Comment: У меня вот так: `var app = express();` ... `module.exports = app;` а в пусковом файле `var app = require('./app');` ... `var server = http.createServer(app);` p.s. я вот уже запутался(

Comment: @sanu0074 говорю же: основное приложение - это `main`. Экспортируйте его. `admin` экспортировать не нужно, потому что оно используется внутри `main`.

Comment: @sanu0074 а вообще, вы могли бы сами попробовать два варианта и посмотреть, какой заработает - и это было бы быстрее, чем ждать от меня ответа.

Comment: спасибо, буду пробовать!

Comment: Извините, но я не смог разобраться, создал отдельную ветку с подробностями: http://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/478879/%D0%A1%D0%BE%D0%B7%D0%B4%D0%B0%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%B5-%D0%BF%D0%BE%D0%B4-%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%B8%D0%BB%D0%BE%D0%B6%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%B9-express-4-x