# Создание под-приложений express 4.x

Tags: node.js, express

К примеру, есть основной файл, основное приложение выглядит так:

```
var app = express();
app.engine("ejs",require("ejs-locals"));
app.set('view engine', 'ejs');
app.set('views', path.join(__dirname, '../front_end/views'));
app.use(express.static(path.join(__dirname, '../front_end/www')));
app.use(favicon(path.join(__dirname, '../front_end/www/img', 'favicon.png')));
app.use(bodyParser.json());
app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({ extended: false }));
app.use(cookieParser());
app.use(session({
     //..
}));
```

Далее я хочу для админки использовать отдельные настройки:

```
var admin = express();
admin.engine("ejs",require("ejs-locals"));
admin.set('view engine', 'ejs');
admin.set('views', path.join(__dirname, '../admin_front_end/views'));
admin.use(express.static(path.join(__dirname, '../admin_front_end/www')));
admin.use(favicon(path.join(__dirname, '../admin_front_end/www/img', 'favicon.png')));
```

Далее подключаем middleware:

```
app.use(require("../middleware/userData"));
admin.use(require("../middleware/userData"));
```

И роуты:

```
require('../routes/index')(app,admin);
```

Содержимое роута выглядит так:

```
module.exports = function(app,admin) {

     //"app" part

    app.use('/', require('routes/app/index'));
    app.use('/login', require('routes/app/login'));

     //"admin" part

    admin.use('/cp', require('routes/admin/admin'));

};
```

И содержимое файла `routes/admin/admin`:

```
var express = require("express");
var router = express.Router();
var Main = require("modules/main/controller");

router.get("/", function(req, res) {
    var main = new Main(res,req);
    main.viewMainPage();
});


module.exports = router;
```

И в итоге, все это не работает, не пойму как приаттачить сюда часть `admin`. Можете объяснить, как правильно сделать?

Comment: *Я же вам писал, вы эту строчку почему-то пропустили...*

Answer (score 1):

Вот так:

```
var admin = express();
// ...

var app = express();
app.use("/admin", admin);
// ...
```

PS **Порядок важен!** Если вам нужно, чтобы подприложение было действительно независимым от основного приложения - то строку `app.use("/admin", admin);` нужно писать сразу после объявления `app`! И уж точно не стоит писать никаких строчек после обработчика ошибок.

Comment: Добавил `app.use("/admin", admin);` и получаю 404 когда пытаюсь зайти куда-нибудь

Comment: Может проблема в самих роутах?

Comment: Я сделал уже все очень по простому: https://jsfiddle.net/f3uLLr9w/ и все-равно получаю 404. Проблема решилась когда закомментил строку `require('../config/errors')(app);` Вот содержимое файла: https://jsfiddle.net/L74zuok0/ Не могли бы вы подсказать в чем конфликт?